# Calling base class's virtual method from derived class instance

Tags: c#, oop

I would like to explain main problem with example.

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public virtual void Add()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Add call from BaseClass");
    }

    public virtual void Edit()
    {

        Console.WriteLine(" Edit call from BaseClass");
        this.Get();
    }

    public virtual void Get()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" Get call from BaseClass");
    }
}


public class DerivedClass:BaseClass
{
    public override void Add()
    {

        Console.WriteLine(" Add call from DerivedClass");
        base.Edit();
    }

    public override void Edit()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" Edit call from DerivedClass");
    }

    public override void Get()
    {

        Console.WriteLine(" Get call from DerivedClass");
    }
}
```

And called like

```
DerivedClass d = new DerivedClass();
d.Add();
```

The result :

1. Add call from DerivedClass
2. Edit call from BaseClass
3. Get call from **DerivedClass**

But I want to get the result as :

1. Add call from DerivedClass
2. Edit call from BaseClass
3. Get call from **BaseClass**

When derived class calls its own  **Add** method, **Add** method calls base class **EDit** method. When base class **edit** method called from derived class it calls **get** method of the **derived class**. but I want to call **base class's get** method.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Side note: you just found that your interface is impossible to understand and implement sensibly. Good point to stop and think about it. One option is to decide if you want complete higher level operations to be overridable (like Edit in your example) or just lower level operations (Add/Remove/Get/Checkout/Checkin) while higer level operations use [template method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) pattern for implementation.

Answer (score 6):

> How can I achieve this?

If you don't want virtual dispatch then *don't dispatch a virtual method*.  Dispatch a non-virtual method.  That implies that a non-virtual method must exist, so let's write one.  Then it becomes obvious how it must be called:

```
public class BaseClass 
{
  public virtual void Add() { ... }
  public virtual void Edit() { this.BaseGet(); }
  public virtual void Get() { this.BaseGet(); }
  private void BaseGet() { ... }
}
```

That's *how* do to what you want, but the more important question here is *why do you want to do this thing?* There is probably a better way to design your class hierarchy, but without knowing more about what you are really trying to do, it is hard to advise you.